# MySQL LEFT JOIN is returning just one row with a where condition on the right table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with events and a second one with events marked as saved by a user.

I need to get **all** the events, and for a certain user to know whether an event is saved or not.

For doing that I am using this SQL

```
SELECT event.id, saved.user_id
FROM event
LEFT JOIN saved on event.id = saved.event_id
```

but then I am getting repeated events, as one event may be marked as saved by many users at the saved table.

Therefore I've added a where condition as

```
SELECT event.id, saved.user_id
FROM event
LEFT JOIN saved on event.id = saved.event_id
where saved.user_id = "71"
```

but surprisingly, the result obtained is reduced to just one row, when I was expecting thousands of them, most of them with saved.user_id to null and only a few or just once with saved.user_id = 71

Ideally I would like to have true/false at the saved.user_id column for a certain user, eg: 71

What is wrong here?

Comment: `Where` clause on right table will **convert** your `left join` to `Inner join`

Comment: ...so change WHERE to AND

Comment: Also, note that id is probably an integer, not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
LEFT JOIN saved on event.id = saved.event_id
where saved.user_id = "71"
```

To:

```
LEFT JOIN saved on event.id = saved.event_id
                   and saved.user_id = "71"
```

Or:

```
LEFT JOIN saved on event.id = saved.event_id
WHERE saved.user_id = "71" OR saved.user_id IS NULL
```

The `where` clause filters data from all tables, the `on` clause just filters the rows from the right-hand table.